# Using inline IF statement vb.net

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

Brief info on the code is as follows. The code takes a bunch of strings and concants them as follows with a if statement in the middle that decides whether to concant or not on one of them. The problem is the `If(Evaluation, "", "")` is complaining saying that it must not be nullable or must be a resource.. How do I work around this when the Evaluation simply checks an object to make sure it IsNot Nothing and also that a property in the object is checked as follows:

```
Dim R as string = stringA & " * sample text" & _
    stringB & " * sample text2" & _
    stringC & " * sameple text3" & _
    If(ApplyValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso ApplyValue.CheckedBox Then ,StringD & " * sample text4" & _
    , NOTHING)
stringE & " * sample text5"
```

VS is complaining about the applyValue. Any Ideas?

Should be noted that I have tried the following just to see if it would work and VS is rejecting it:

```
Dim y As Double
Dim d As String = "string1 *" & _
    "string2 *" & _
    If(y IsNot Nothing, " * sample text4", "") & _
    "string4 *"
```

This is what it is flagging the y with:

```
  'IsNot' requires operands that have reference types, but this operand has the value type 'Double'.    C:\Users\Skindeep\AppData\Local\Temporary Projects\WindowsApplication1\Form1.vb 13  16  WindowsApplication1
```

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Use the IIF ternary expression evaluator

```
Dim R as string = stringA & " * sample text" & _
                  stringB & " * sample text2" & _
                  stringC & " * sameple text3" & _
                  IIf(ApplyValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso ApplyValue.CheckedBox, StringD & " * sample text4", "") & _
                  stringE & " * sample text5"
```

EDIT: If you use VB.NET from ver 2008 onward you could use also the

```
IF(expression,truepart,falsepart)
```

and this is even better because it provides the short-circuit functionality.

```
Dim R as string = stringA & " * sample text" & _
                  stringB & " * sample text2" & _
                  stringC & " * sameple text3" & _
                  If(ApplyValue IsNot Nothing AndAlso ApplyValue.CheckedBox, StringD & " * sample text4", "") & _
                  stringE & " * sample text5"
```

Comment: Thanks much guess I should go read up on this IIF statement as I have seen it mentioned in other posts...

Comment: @Steve I have tried the above which looks right but if you look at my edit you will see what it is saying.. It should be noted that I know that in my example I have not assigned any value to y. In the actual code where this is used y is assigned a value or remains 0.0 Any ideas???  Further it should be noted that my OP was the exact same thing you posted, the problem was not even looked at... Why am I getting a VS flag on the expression???

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, but y is a value type (not nullable) and the vb compiler complains about IsNot used against a value type, while has nothing to say when you use a reference type like ApplyValue.