# IsNothing() Function on Windows Phone 8.x

Tags: .net, vb.net

What is the equivalent to VB .NET's `if IsNothing(object) then work()` ?

Comment: Here is a answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13661200/using-inline-if-statement-vb-net

Comment: Your question should be: What is the equivalent to VB .NET's `whatever code` in language XY. Windows Phone 8.x is not a language!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this?

```
If obj Is Nothing Then
      'Do something
End If
```

UPDATE: I suppose you wanted to convert that expression from vb.net pc application to Silverlight/Win RT version. If so, I have to say that the code above works on both pc and Windows Phone.